# How to verify the Leaflet Marker being clicked is the one I want based on its popup information?

Tags: jquery, leaflet

In leaflet some of my markers are built like this;

```
$div1 = "<div class='xx'>OBJ: $objmrkr<br></div><div class='gg'>W3W: $w3w</div>";                          //echo "$div1<br>";   
        $div2 = "<div class='cc'>Comment:<br>$comment</div>";               //echo "$div2<br>";
        $div3 = "<div class='bb'><br>Cross Roads:<br>$cr</div><br><div class='gg'>$row[lat],$row[lng]<br>Grid: $gs<br><br>Captured:<br>$row[timestamp]</div>";  //echo "$div3<br>";
        
        
        $objMarkers .= " var $objmrkr = new L.marker(new L.LatLng($row[lat],$row[lng]),{
                            rotationAngle: $dup, 
                            rotationOrigin: 'bottom', 
                            opacity: 0.75,
                            contextmenu: true, 
                            contextmenuWidth: 140,
                            contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles',callback: circleKoords}],
                            
                            icon: L.icon({iconUrl: '$markername', iconSize: [32, 34]}),
                            title:`marker_$markNO`}).addTo(fg).bindPopup(`$div1<br>$div2<br>$div3`).openPopup();                    
                            
                            $('Objects'._icon).addClass('objmrkr'); 
                                       
                       ";
        };
```

When right clicked on the circleKoords function is called, but before its code is run I need to know if I have the correct marker. The correct markers have an 'OBJ:' in the title like the example. This seems like a clumsy way to do this but I don't know another. My question is how do I verify that 'OBJ:' is in the popup of this marker?
There are a number of similar questions on SO but none of them seems to work, I'm not sure if its because I'm using contextmenu or something else.
I tried;
var imanobj = e.xx kind of things but nothing seems to get what I need?
Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the content of the popup (of the marker) `marker.getPopup().getContent()` and then you can check with `content.indexOf("OBJ") > -1` if it contains the string.

```
marker.on('contextmenu',(e)=>{
  var marker = e.target;
  if(marker.getPopup()){
    var popup = marker.getPopup();
    if(popup.getContent().indexOf("OBJ") > -1){
        alert('Clicked Marker has OBJ')
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/54hoaerx/

### Other way to set the `OBJ` flag:

If you want to know if the marker is a `OBJ-Marker`, you can simply add a property flag. `$objmrkr.objFlag = true;`

```
$objMarkers .= " var $objmrkr = new L.marker(new L.LatLng($row[lat],$row[lng]),{
                            rotationAngle: $dup, 
                            rotationOrigin: 'bottom', 
                            opacity: 0.75,
                            contextmenu: true, 
                            contextmenuWidth: 140,
                            contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles',callback: circleKoords}],
                            
                            icon: L.icon({iconUrl: '$markername', iconSize: [32, 34]}),
                            title:`marker_$markNO`}).addTo(fg).bindPopup(`$div1<br>$div2<br>$div3`).openPopup();                    
                            
                            $('Objects'._icon).addClass('objmrkr'); 
                   $objmrkr.objFlag = true;
                       ";
```

```
marker.on('contextmenu',(e)=>{
  var marker = e.target;
  if(marker.objFlag){
        alert('Clicked Marker is a OBJ-Marker')
  }
})
```

### Implementation of the listener in the php string:

(I have not checked if there any php errors)

```
$objMarkers .= " var $objmrkr = new L.marker(new L.LatLng($row[lat],$row[lng]),{
        rotationAngle: $dup,
        rotationOrigin: 'bottom',
        opacity: 0.75,
        contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuWidth: 140,
        contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles',callback: circleKoords}],
        
        icon: L.icon({iconUrl: '$markername', iconSize: [32, 34]}),
        title:`marker_$markNO`}).addTo(fg).bindPopup(`$div1<br>$div2<br>$div3`).openPopup();

        $('Objects'._icon).addClass('objmrkr');

        $objmrkr.on('contextmenu',function(e){
            var marker = e.target;
            if(marker.getPopup()){
                var popup = marker.getPopup();
                if(popup.getContent().indexOf('OBJ') > -1){
                    alert('Clicked Marker has OBJ')
                }
            }
        })";
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this answer. I just need to figure out how to use the marker.on you provided.

Comment: you only need to add the `marker.on` code in the php string. And you need to change the variable name `marker` with `$objmrkr`. I updated the answer to show you

Comment: I replaced my code with your but unfortunately I get an 'end of file error'. To me this usually means I'm missing a tick, or a comma or paren, or etc. so I searched for that but didn't find anything. So I read and re-read your comment about changing the variable marker to $objmrkr changed the end to say; "$objmrker.on('context menu',(e)=>{...." but that ends with; Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /var/www/html/objMarkers.php on line 106". You can see I'm struggling with syntax issues. I'm not sure if that last part is after the '};' or before both gave same result

Comment: One more quick question. I set a variable ' var isOBJ = 1 ' in your code. But when I test for it in another function the console.log says "can't find variable isOBJ". How would I do this?

Comment: Can you please share your code? For example over jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have put the circlekoords() function on jsfiddle but all I really need to do is validate that the clicked marker is defined for my use as an object. You did that for me. Now I have to use that information in my function as a switch to change between one set of circles and another. The fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/kkaiser/2um17c5e/1/  I've only used jsfiddle a few times so I hope that's correct.

Comment: And where do you create the variable `isOBJ`? Do you create it in the global scope / outside of a function and before you call the function `circlekoords`?

Comment: Its created in the code you provided me.   $objmrkr.on('contextmenu',function(e){
                               
                                var marker = e.target;
                                if(marker.getPopup()){
                                    var popup = marker.getPopup();
                                    if(popup.getContent().indexOf('OBJ:') > -1){
                                        
                                            var isOBJ = '1';  ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231590/discussion-between-keith-d-kaiser-and-falke-design).